# Make a slider based image collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, slider

I want to make a slider based image collection, or one might say a slider based corousel.
The slider that I have in mind has specific markings on it, ( say 1990,1995,2000, et cetera), and there is an image corresponding to the range in which the slider currently is (That is, one image for 1990-1995, another one for 1995-2000, and so on). The images are not necessarily to slide in and out of the visual. So, a Bootstrap corousel isn't necessary.

The slider that I am looking into is [this](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle), which I'll modify according to my needs.

So, I tried to merge these two concepts. The two elements shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c5v8mwj2/1/) fiddle are not attached to each other whatsoever. Then I tried to [mess around with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/c5v8mwj2/3/), but the corousel still seems to be unaffected by the slider's movements.

Here is the code after the messing around:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 



      <style>
  #custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  </style>

  <script>
    $( function() {
        var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
        create: function() {
        var slide_number = Number($(this).slider("value"))/34+1 ;
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        $("#carouselExampleIndicators").data('slide-to',slide_number) ;
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var slide_number = Number(ui.value)/34+1 ;
        handle.text( ui.value );
        $("#corouselExampleIndicators").data('slide-to',slide_number) ;
        }
        });
    } );
    </script>    
</head>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide"  >
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/S7Hebtq.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://procutlandscaping.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/landscape-design-rockland-county.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7Tjc6muCHKc/UIToU_6RXeI/AAAAAAAAC4Q/2iE7Cb0m5ZU/s1600/Beautiful+-Landscape-+HD-+Wallpapers3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
    <script>
        $(function(){
          $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel();
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div>
     <br><br>
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

The main part that is not working is :

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
        create: function() {
        var slide_number = Number($(this).slider("value"))/34+1 ;
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        $("#carouselExampleIndicators").data('slide-to',slide_number) ;
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var slide_number = Number(ui.value)/34+1 ;
        handle.text( ui.value );
        $("#corouselExampleIndicators").data('slide-to',slide_number) ;
        }
        });
    } );
    </script>
```

The errors I get are:

> TypeError: Actions[t.getLast(...)] is undefined, can't access property
>   "bind" of it

and

> TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

The corousel is working fine, therefore I don't understand why the second error is coming. Meanwhile, I don't understand the first error too.

So, my question here is, why this doesn't work?

Secondly, is there a better way to do this?

Thirdly, can I write better code for this?

Any help appreciated!

---

**UPD**: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5v8mwj2/5/).

---

**UPD**: Changed `$("#corouselExampleIndicators").data('slide-to',slide_number) ;` to `$('.corousel').corousel(slider_number) ;`, as given [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#carouselnumber). But this still doesn't work, and the slider has stopped working now. Look at the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c5v8mwj2/6/).

Tried to use the `id` instead of the `class`, in the code,  that is, used `$('#corouselExampleIndicators').corousel(1) ;`. Still nothing worked.

---

**UPD:** If anyone is interested, the final version can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmeanog1/2/). This works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are including many versions of jQuery that conflict with each other and cause an error in the page `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function`

So, remove this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And resort the scripts to be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Update: Due to question updates.**

I found another two typo bugs inside your last updated fiddle at the following line:

```
$('.corousel').corousel(slider_number) ;
```

It 's `carousel` not `corousel` and it's `slide_number` not `slider_number`. So, it should be

```
$('.corousel').carousel(slide_number) ;
```

Note: The script includes this buggy line twice.

Check new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmeanog1/

Comment: Yes, there is no error now. Any help on the slider though?

Comment: And why the particular sequence of scripts? I understand the first one, but the order of 2 and 3 isn't clear. If I exchange the 2nd and the 3rd scripts, will the results be the same?

Comment: @Mooncrater, Regarding "And why the particular sequence of scripts?", as every script depends on the previous. Imagine that the first script creates a function `fn_x` the second script calls this function and creates another function `fn_y` which the third script calls and so on...
If I answered your question please mark this answer as accepted and if you have any further questions feel free to create new question and give me a link to check if i can help.

Comment: Thanks @Mouneer! Final fiddle, that works as required is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmeanog1/2/). Had to add `Math.floor` for proper working.